# c++ check if value in range ( A < B < C verse A<b && B<C )

Tags: c++, compare

I would like to check if value B is between A and C ,
my first try is `if(A < B < C)` , however the result is not right ,after I try `if(A < B && B < C)` and it works well

The second method is intuitive to me , but I do not know why first one fails and what C++ actually does in `if(A < B < C)` operation？
Can someone explains to me , Thanks!

Comment: You can't chain relational operators. What really happens is  `A < B` will evaluate to `1` or `0` and that'll be compared with `C`.

Comment: A good [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be preferred to random coding.

Comment: In Python (where I guess you've seen this) a "logical chain" like `a < b < c` is shorthand for `a < b and b < c`. Very few languages work like Python in that regard. (Note that in Python, you can also write weird things like  `3 > 2 < 5 in [2,3,4]`.)

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the `<` operator has [left-to-right associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). That means your expression `A < B < C` can be written (more verbosely) as `(A < B) < C`. First, `A < B` is evaluated, say `res`. Then, that intermediate result is used to evaluate `res < C` which is ultimately used by the `if` statement.

And, as you can see that it is very much different from the expression `A < B && B < C`.

Answer (score 0):

`A < B` evaluates to a boolean value, so then you're comparing `C` to a boolean.

`true < C` doesn't make sense, no? Unless `C` itself is a boolean, in which case, why are you using less/greater than haha.